# Dual boot using an SSD and HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

So what I'm trying to achieve may have already been answered, but I just can't find any existing threads.

Basically I'm installing Ubuntu for the first time and I've just bought a 250gb HDD to dual boot it with my existing Windows 10 installation on a NVMe SSD.

There's a couple of things I'm unsure of whilst going through this process.

1. Is it possible to have GRUB installed on the SSD for a faster load up instead of having it on the HDD with the rest of the Ubuntu installation? And if so, do I need to create a separate partition for it? (Is this what 'Device for bootloader installation' in the setup refers to?)
2. If I was to proceed with putting only GRUB on the SSD and the rest of the installation on the HDD, would I be correct in assuming that I can set the boot option to the SSD, it will load up GRUB and I can select whichever operating system I'd like to boot into from there?

Any help is appreciated, thanks :)

edit: if anyone ends up facing this problem in the future I'll just explain what I ended up doing. I set the device for bootloader installation to my SSD with the windows installation for a faster boot up whilst keeping the rest of the install on the HDD. I then used GRUB customizer to set the default boot option to Windows and changed the timer to 3 seconds before it automatically boots into the OS. There's really no extra steps and you don't go through the windows bootloader after GRUB, it just automatically boots in.

Comment: Even if you put the GRUB bootloader on the SSD, the stuff it got to load is on the HDD. Why not put the Ubuntu root partition, (/) on the SSD and put the home partition, (/home), on the HDD. It is also simple to move Windows "user" folders such as Desktop, Documents, Downloads, etc, to the HDD.

Comment: The computer I'm installing this on is for my whole family to use, so I don't want to impact them being able to use Windows in any way. That's why I bought a new HDD to keep it completely separate from Windows.

Comment: Best perhaps to just put the whole Ubuntu install on the new HDD. The family might not appreciate having to boot through GRUB in addition to the Windows bootloader. If Ubuntu is installed on the HDD it's GRUB should also be able to boot Windows, You can make Windows default HDD to keep the family happy. Having Ubuntu on the HDD is probably the best choice. If there is enough RAM, Ubuntu will mostly run in it and be plenty fast.